# Sort the key:value pairs wrt value

Tags: python, key-value

A column in the test excel that I'm loading looks something like this:

```
Apple:3, Mango:2, Orange:2, Fig:5, Berry:1, Cherry:99
```

This is in a single column.

I am trying this using python.

There are 100 rows which contains records like this in a single column.

I am trying to split it into different columns. I have tried to split ",". I just am not able to get it right with anything

Now I want the out put of the sort like this

```
Cherry:99,Fig:5,Apple:3,Mango:2,Orange:2,Berry:1
```

Comment: "not able to get it right with anything" - with _what code_, exactly? Please post your code and explain what doesn't work.

Comment: Try using the csv module to load your data.

Comment: @ForceBru I have tried using split(",") to separate them into different key:value pairs, but it didn't change anything. I tried using partition keeping ':' as the keyword to see if that would work but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex with `sorted`

**Ex:**

```
import re
data = "Apple:3, Mango:2, Orange:2, Fig:5, Berry:1, Cherry:99"
print(", ".join(sorted(data.split(", "), key=lambda x: int(re.search(r"(\d+)", x).group(1)), reverse=True)))
```

**Output:**

```
Cherry:99, Fig:5, Apple:3, Mango:2, Orange:2, Berry:1
```

- `int(re.search(r"(\d+)", x).group(1))` to find the integer in the string.

---

For Pandas DF

**Ex:**

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"data": ["Apple:3, Mango:2, Orange:2, Fig:5, Berry:1, Cherry:99"]})
df["data"] = df["data"].apply(lambda z: ", ".join(sorted(z.split(", "), key=lambda x: int(re.search(r"(\d+)", x).group(1)), reverse=True)))
print(df)
```

Comment: Since I'm running this on excel column. 'Series' object has no attribute 'split' that is the error I'm facing

Comment: Do you have a pandas DF?

Answer (score 0):

> **Python sorted()**
>
> The sorted() method returns a sorted list from the given iterable.
>
> ```
> Syntax : sorted(iterable, key, reverse)
> ```
>
> Parameters : sorted takes three parameters from which two are
>   optional.
>
> *Iterable* : sequence (list, tuple, string) or collection (dictionary,
>   set, frozenset) or any other iterator that needs to be sorted.
>
> *Key(optional)* : A function that would server as a key or a basis of
>   sort comparison.
>
> *Reverse(optional)* : If set true, then the iterable
>   would be sorted in reverse (descending) order, by default it is set as
>   false.

```
data = {'Apple':3, 'Mango':2, 'Orange':2, 'Fig':5, 'Berry':1, 'Cherry':99}
sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)
print (dict(sorted_data))
```

output:

```
{'Cherry': 99, 'Fig': 5, 'Apple': 3, 'Mango': 2, 'Orange': 2, 'Berry': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
row = "Apple:3, Mango:2, Orange:2, Fig:5, Berry:1, Cherry:99"

key_value_pairs_list = [x.lstrip().rstrip() for x in  row.split(",")]

key_value_pairs_dict = {}
for value in key_value_pairs_list:
    fruit, count = value.split(':')
    key_value_pairs_dict[fruit] = count

sorted_data = sorted(key_value_pairs_dict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)

new_str = ", ".join([key + ':' + str(value) for key, value in sorted_data])
print(new_str)
```